# How to calculate angular magnification of a convex lens when image is formed at infinity?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

When an object is placed in front of a convex lens at its principal focus, image is formed at infinity. I wonder how to calculate how large this image will be. I mean what is the magnification in this case?

Comment: Use angular magnification and compare the visual angle formed at infinity with the visual angle of the image when it is formed at the near point of the eye.

Comment: @Farcher Focal length of a convex lens is 5cm. What is the angular magnification when the final image is formed at infinity?

Comment: I am not here to do your homework.  I have given you all the information you need. http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/geoopt/simmag.html